# Как спарсить с консоли римские цифры и сохранить в переменные по отдельности? (Java)

Tags: java

Пусть от I до X вводится в консоль для сложения два числа. Конвертировать в арабские я знаю как. А вот как прочитать введенные римские цифры и сохранить каждая в свою переменную не понимаю.

для арабских парсинг

```
    int firstNumber, secondNumber;
String operation; 
String numOperationNum = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");
if(numOperationNum.length != 3){
    System.out.println("Неверный формат ввода");
} else {
    firstNumber =  Integer.parseInt(numOperationNum[0]);
    operation = numOperationNum[1];
    secondNumber =  Integer.parseInt(numOperationNum[2]);
}
```

Comment: Так римские цифры в строковом виде (типа "IV") не спарсятся же просто так в int. Вы же написали, что конвертировать знаете как.

Comment: я привел для арабских парсинг

Comment: Ясно. Формулировочки у вас, однако. Из вашего "Конвертировать в арабские я знаю как" следует, что вы знаете как строку с римским числом привести к типу int. Но теперь я поняла, что не знаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = in.next();
```

Или, если вводится строка типа "III + IV", то:

```
String userInput = in.nextLine();
String[] str = userInput.split(" "); // так введенная строка попадет в массив
str[0]; // в этой переменной будет лежать "III"
str[1]; // в этой переменной будет лежать "+"
str[2]; // в этой переменной будет лежать "IV"
```

Comment: непрваильный ответ, у меня два числа на входе + знак операции, то есть как спарсить след строку I + X и сохранить в отдельные переменные

Comment: да мне их надо в переменные сохранить по отдельности

Comment: `in.nextLine()` - получаете строку, затем препарируете ее как вам нужно... например раскидываете в String-массив по частям.

Comment: для меня это тяжело разбить массив по частям

Comment: `String[] str = userInput.split(" ");` так вы получите массив в котором будут лежать все ваши числа и знаки математических операций в том порядке, в котором вы их вводили через пробел

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть множество таких строк, но числа и операция строго разделены пробелом, то можно сделать так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] splittedLine = line.split(" ");
        String firstNumber = splittedLine[0];
        String secondNumber = splittedLine[2];
        String operation = splittedLine[1];

        // doSomeAction(firstNumber, secondNumber, operation);
    }
}
```

Если операция разделения более сложная, чем обычный пробел, то можно подставить регулярное выражение в метод `split`.